# ASP.Net with VB doesn't seems to work: how to use '@'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've followed the example in this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/showfile_vb.asp?filename=try_razor_vb_005

but actual result was this:

```
@for i=10 to 21
   @Line @i
  next i
```

It seems to both IE and Firefox dosen't seem to recognize the symbol '@'.

Has anyone the solution?

Comment: `@<p>Line @i</p>` set it to a paragraph tag... It has to be in the asp...

Comment: It isn't the browser which processes the razor syntax, it is the web server.

Comment: Okay, I got it.